# Reading a file inside jar in java

Tags: java, file, text, jar, loading

I have a situation where i have a txt file and java file bundled inside jar. I am reading txt file from java which is bundled inside jar only.

While reading file, getting `FileNotFoundException` in Java and where as txt file is in same folder bundled inside jar.

I am calling this Java method from a test class sample code.

```
public static void loadtxtfile(){

    try {  
        InputStream in = 
            Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.txt");


         File f = new File(JetUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dd.js").getFile());
         //OJetBase.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties");

          BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(js_filepath));
          StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

          while ((text = input.readLine()) != null)
              buffer.append(text + "\n");
          java_script = buffer.toString();
}
```

Test call - `Utils.loadtxtfile()`;

I tried all the options.

Comment: You are gathering `File f = ` from the `ClassLoader` and then use `new FileReader(`**js_filepath**`)`.

Comment: You can't use `File` on resources in the classpath!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read resources from a jar file as a java.io.File object because they do not exist in a file system. Just use [java.lang.Classloader.getResourceAsStream(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

```
Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                JetUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dd.js"));
BufferedReader jsReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

StringBuilder javascript = new StringBuilder();
String input;
while ((input = jsReader.readln()) != null) {
    javascript.append(input);
}
```